# How load canvas from json with events?

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I save canvas json with `JSON.stringify(canvas)`, when i am use `canvas.loadFromJSON(json)`, all canvas object are exists and all right, but events on canvas elements does not work and default canvas settings (as renderOnAddRemove, selection) does not work; What i do wrong? Sorry for my English.

Comment: Are you using JSON.parse(json) when you brink back the information you need? <-- EDIT:  Ignore this. I see you are using Fabric.js - check the documentation on the website.

Comment: Thank you Brian, for reply) I necessarily read the documentation again, but i don't found there information about my problem.

Comment: I think we need to see your code to really help you.